# Need to Copy file Size of about 14 MB to clipboard using Clipboard.js

Tags: javascript

I need to copy the content to Clipboard using JavaScript. I used Clipboard.js to copy the content to clipboard. Its working fine for copying files of size about 1 MB. I need to copy file Size of about 14 MB. But the content is not getting copied. If I keep break point in clipboard.js file and debug then the content is getting copied. Can any one please help in solving this issue..

Comment: Add some code that your tried?

Comment: var clip = new Clipboard('.btn');
$(document).ready(function() {

    clip.on('success', function(e) {
        $scope.docstatus = "Copied!";

        e.clearSelection();
    });

    clip.on('error', function(e) {


        $scope.docstatus = "Copy Failed.."



    });

});